# When should I care about the hierarchical structure of a few included studies for a meta-analysis (multiple independent groups, same outcome)?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I plan to meta-analyze proportion data (i.e. compliance rates in %) from >150 studies. Most of the studies will be single-group designs, but there will also be a few eligible multiple group studies (case-control or intervention-control) providing one effect size for each group. I consider the groups being indepently sampled, but some correlation between the results, because the groups underwent the same study protocol.
For my pre-registration, I would like to define an **a-priori decision rule** at what proportion of nested effect-sizes within my selected studies I will start modelling the multi-level structure of the effect-sizes. At 5% of all ES or 10%, 15%, 20% ?
A sensitivity analysis will be run post-hoc.

Follow-up question: Do I need to specify a covariance-matrix for such a hierarchical structure in metafor?
Sidenote: I am not mixing different effect-sizes from the same people.

**Thanks for helping me with my pre-registration !** You receive double karma points.